# Error while starting jboss 5.0.0 in Springsource STS eclipse (STS version 2.6)

Tags: eclipse, jboss5.x, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have just downloaded the jboss version 5.0.0. I have added  it as the server in my STS (2.6).

The jboss 5.0.0 runs properly when run using command prompt. But when it is run from eclipse it gives following error.

```
java.lang.LinkageError: JAXB 2.0 API is being loaded from the bootstrap classloader, but this RI (from vfszip:/E:/servers/dimexserver/jboss-5.0.0.GA/lib/jaxb-impl.jar/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/impl/ModelBuilder.class) needs 2.1 API. Use the endorsed directory mechanism to place jaxb-api.jar in the bootstrap classloader. (See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/standards/)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.<clinit>(ModelBuilder.java:173)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:432)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:297)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:139)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:117)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:210)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:368)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)
at org.jboss.resource.deployers.ManagedConnectionFactoryParserDeployer.create(ManagedConnectionFactoryParserDeployer.java:106)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59)
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150)
at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:241)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:109)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:70)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.LifecycleAction.installActionInternal(LifecycleAction.java:221)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:774)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:540)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:121)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:51)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:545)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.loadProfile(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:297)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:205)
at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:405)
at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:209)
at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:547)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

09:55:13,991 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] JBoss Web Services - Stack Native Core
09:55:13,991 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] 3.0.4.SP1
09:55:16,012 ERROR [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Failed to load profile: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

*** CONTEXTS IN ERROR: Name -> Error

ManagedConnectionFactoryParserDeployer -> java.lang.LinkageError: JAXB 2.0 API is being loaded from the bootstrap classloader, but this RI (from vfszip:/E:/servers/dimexserver/jboss-5.0.0.GA/lib/jaxb-impl.jar/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/impl/ModelBuilder.class) needs 2.1 API. Use the endorsed directory mechanism to place jaxb-api.jar in the bootstrap classloader. (See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/standards/)

I am using jdk 6.0.

I have googled and found few links http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ramapulavarthi/archive/2007/01/problems_using.html which explains a solution.

I have tried this but no success so far.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the jaxb-api.jar into JDK_HOME/jre/lib/endorsed. If the endorsed directory doesn't exist, make it. This is apparently only a problem with JDK 1.6, not with JDK 1.5